# Make product out of stock after specified date

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have listed an event booking on my website in magento,
in that i have specified of event, i would like to edit the product out of stock functionality such that it would put that product out of stock automatically when it reaches the event date.

I am new to these php coding, but i can surely give it a try if anyone can help me with code and direction.

Will be very thankfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this event observer

```
 <controller_action_layout_render_before>
```

and put you condition on model method on date.

Answer (score 0):

My point of view, you can use Group Deal Module. Because it already have start and end date. Also we can set max. no. of purchase as target.